# PostgreSQL trying to get multiple unique rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get multiple unique rows in a query, the table I'm working with it is:

**settings**

| id | category_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | phone | +2222222222 |
| 2 | 1 | phone | +1111111111 |
| 3 | null | email | email@gmail.com |

So there is a default settings with a null value, and each category can have their own settings, the query that I'm running is:

```
SELECT MAX(category_id), key, value
FROM settings
WHERE key IN('phone', 'email')
AND (category_id IS NULL OR category_id = 1)
GROUPBY key, value;
```

But instead return me one value per key, returns both rows.

I want the query return me something like this:

| id | category_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | phone | +1111111111 |
| 3 | null | email | email@gmail.com |

if the category_id exists just return that row, not the row with category_id null

Comment: You are grouping by `value`. Since all three rows have different values in it, the query will produce three rows. Please add the expected result to the question.

Comment: Ah... seems like the row with `1` has more value than the row with `null`. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah, values are differents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can only `GROUP BY key`, so you need to add a aggregation function for value, depending on what you want

```
SELECT MAX(category_id), key, MIN(value)
FROM settings
WHERE key IN('phone', 'email')
AND (category_id IS NULL OR category_id = 1)
GROUP BY key;
```

| max | key | min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | email | email@gmail.com |
| 1 | phone | +1111111111 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AUA5E9Y9)